# Generate an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following which is only a sample of the final data format, the final one will have 7 dates and for each date there will 24hrs with 2 values for each hour:

```
var matrixData = {
    "header": [
        "Date",
        "Total",
        "Breakdown"
    ],
    "data": [
        [
            "2014-06-05",
            5340,
            {
                "header": [
                    "BookingCount",
                    "LastYearDifference"
                ],
                "data": [
                    [ 506, 46 ],
                    [ 524, 34 ],
                    [ 448, 25 ]
                ]
            }
        ],
        [
            "2014-06-06",
            14339,
            {
                "header": [
                    "BookingCount",
                    "LastYearDifference"
                ],
                "data": [
                    [ 506, 46 ],
                    [ 432, 92 ],
                    [ 498, 37 ]
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

which I have to pass into a [jQuery load template](https://github.com/codepb/jquery-template/blob/master/Examples/OptionalBinding/example.html)

like this one:

```
<script type="text/html" id="tableContent">
    <tr>
        <td data-content="Date"></td>
        <td  data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCoun"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="BookingCount"></td>
        <td data-content="Total"></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

I have come up with the followwing and I can get what I need to build my table inside a 'console.log()':

```
function generateObject() {
    var newarray = [],
        thing;

    //console.log(matrixData);

    for (var i = 0; i < matrixData.data.length; i++) {
        console.log('Date: '+matrixData.data[i][0]);
        console.log('Total: '+matrixData.data[i][1]);
        thing = {};
        for (var y = 0; y < matrixData.data[i][2].data.length; y++) {
            console.log('for each hour: '+matrixData.data[i][2].data[y]);
        }
    }
}
```

However I don't know (maybe push everything in an array?) how to transform it so that I can pass it inside that jQuery template and have my table built.

The expected value suppose to be something like this:

```
[
    ['05-12-2011',[400, 200], [400, 200], [400, 200], [400, 200], ....... x 24, 7896 ]
    ..the above row will have to be repeated 7 times as per 7 days of the week
];
```

Comment: @Fyodor thanks for the sidenote, I guess I need to work on JSON skills.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @Mritunjay check my latest update please

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you er unable to figure out how to structure the data and build the template code.

I think it is a good idea to have:

```
var data = {
  rows: [{
    date: 'somedate',
    counts: [50, 100, 250],
    total: 400
  }]
}
```

I am not very familiar with jQuery templates, but I would expect something like this to work:

```
<script type="text/html" id="tableContent">
  <tr data-content="rows" data-format="nestedTemplateFormatter"  data-format-options="#row"></tr>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="row">
    <td data-content-append="date"></td>
    <td data-content="counts" data-format="nestedTemplateFormatter" data-format-options="#count"></td>
    <td data-content-append="total"></td>
</script>
```

Then you would have to create a template for #count. I am not sure if you can like use "this" to point to the count value, or you would have to put objects into the counts array, like [{count: 50}, {count: 100}] etc. and then use data-content-append="count" on a span inside the #count template.